# Variable with line break (\n) in PdfMake

Tags: typescript, ionic3, pdfmake

I'm trying to pass a variable that contains line break character (\n) to a table in PdfMake (inside an Ionic 3 project), but the generated PDF doesn't treat the line break character as a new line.

```
table: {
        
        headerRows: 1,
        widths: ["80%", "20%"],

        body: [
          [
            { text: "Job Description", style: "center" },
            { text: "Total", style: "center" },
          ],
          [
            // JobDescriotiob is a string variable that contains \n character
            { text: JobDescription, style: "center" },
            { text: Price, style: "center" },
          ],
        ],
      },
```

Result is

[image]

However, (\n) works well when I use it in a text directly

```
table: {
        
        headerRows: 1,
        widths: ["80%", "20%"],

        body: [
          [
            { text: "Job Description", style: "center" },
            { text: "Total", style: "center" },
          ],
          [
            { text: "test\nfff", style: "center" },
            { text: Price, style: "center" },
          ],
        ],
      },
```

Result is

[image]

Is there any way to pass a line break with the variable?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by replacing any character in jobdescription with "\n"

```
    JobDescription = JobDescription.split("--").join("\n");
```

Comment: How does "- -" work as a delimiter? Is it a special 'split' syntax?

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
JobDescription = JobDescription.concat("\n");
```